# URL remains the same even when it navigates to other pages

Tags: asp.net

When I am requesting a page, it navigates to that page but the URL does not change, it does not showing anything other than USERLOGIN.aspx.

When it was in Java script, it was working fine. But after we implementing CSS3,this problem arose.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Have you started to use Server.Transfer() ? If so try Response.Redirect() instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something's not set correctly in the web.config, so you're being redirected to login and authenticate yourself. Check the `<authorization>` element and [set permissions if necessary](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871).

Comment: Thanks for the help